# Open source fuzz tool for fuzzing HTTP POST requests

Tags: http-post, fuzzer

I am looking for an open source fuzz tool for fuzzing HTTP POST requests. Any ideas?

Comment: By "fuzz" do you mean something to generate random/unexpected/invalid POSTs? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fuzzer](http://gitorious.org/fuzzer/fuzz-xmlrpc)